# Convert string datatype of a key to array in response json

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am not able to make data type of key from string to array response json.(after hitting get api call)

Response Json

```
{
    "itemList": [
        {
            "subCategory": "Bread",
            "selectedQuantity": "Half & Full",
            "productId": 14,
            "name": "Fish Curry",
            "cuisine": "Indian",
            "description": "Fish Gravy Masala",
            "isAdd": true,
            "category": "Starter",
            "quantityOption": "[{\"option\":\"Half\", \"price\":100,  \"quantity\":2},{\"option\":\"Full\", \"price\":200,  \"quantity\":4}]"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Reuirement is how to remove double quote in value "quantityOption" key**

**The DAO implementation Class**

```
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String getQuery="SELECT a.productId as productId, a.category as category, a.subCategory as subCategory," +
                "a.cuisine as cuisine, a.description as description, a.name as name, a.isAdd as isAdd , a.selectedQuantity as selectedQuantity, " +
               "CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT('{\"option\":\"', b.option, '\", \"price\":',b.price,',  \"quantity\":',b.quantity,'}'),']') as quantityOption " +
                "FROM Product as a join  a.quantityOption as b GROUP BY a.productId";
        Query query = session.createQuery(getQuery).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

        List<Product> products=query.list();
        session.flush();
        // it will close the particular session after completing the process
        session.close();
        return products;
    }
```

**Controler API **

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getAllProducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getAllProducts(Model model) {
        List<Product> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("itemList", products);
        return "jsonTemplate";
```

** Product Table which has child table Quantityoption**

```
package com.model;


import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
//@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5186013952828648626L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "productId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int productId;

    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    /*@Column(name="Type")
    private String productType;*/
    @Column(name="subCategory")
    private String subCategory;

    @Column(name="cuisine")
    private String cuisine;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    /*@Column(name = "manufacturer")
    private String productManufacturer;*/

    @NotEmpty(message = "Product Name is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    /*@NotNull(message="Please provide some price")
    @Min(value = 100, message = "Minimum value should be greater than 100")
    @Column(name = "price")
    private double productPrice;*/

    /*@Column(name = "unit")
    private int unitStock;*/

    /*@Column(name = "itemStatus")
    private boolean itemStatus;*/

    @Column(name = "isAdd")
    private Boolean isAdd;

    /*@Column(name= "preparationTime")
    private double pTime;*/

    @Column(name="selectedQuantity")
    private  String selectedQuantity;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ProductQuantityOptions> quantityOption;

    /*@Transient
    private MultipartFile productImage;*/



    public Product() {


    }

    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
        return other instanceof Product;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public String getSubCategory() {
        return this.subCategory;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return this.cuisine;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAdd() {
        return this.isAdd;
    }

    public String getSelectedQuantity() {
        return this.selectedQuantity;
    }

    public List<ProductQuantityOptions> getQuantityOption() {
        return this.quantityOption;
    }

    /*public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
        return this.productImage;
    }*/

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setSubCategory(String subCategory) {
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setIsAdd(Boolean isAdd) {
        this.isAdd = isAdd;
    }

    public void setSelectedQuantity(String selectedQuantity) {
        this.selectedQuantity = selectedQuantity;
    }

    public void setQuantityOption(List<ProductQuantityOptions> quantityOption) {
        this.quantityOption = quantityOption;
    }

    /*public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }*/

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "productId=" + productId +
                ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                ", subCategory='" + subCategory + '\'' +
                ", cuisine='" + cuisine + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", isAdd=" + isAdd +
                ", selectedQuantity='" + selectedQuantity + '\'' +
                ", quantityOption=" + quantityOption +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
package com.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "itemQuantity")
public class ProductQuantityOptions implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int QOId;

    @Column(name="qoption")
    private String option;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @NotNull(message="Please provide some price")
    @Min(value = 50, message = "Minimum value should be greater than 50")
    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    /*@JsonIgnore*/
    private Product product;

    public ProductQuantityOptions() {
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof ProductQuantityOptions;
    }

    public int getQOId() {
        return this.QOId;
    }

    public String getOption() {
        return this.option;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setQOId(int QOId) {
        this.QOId = QOId;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }


}
```

The result json should be like this

```
{
    "itemList": [
        {
            "subCategory": "Bread",
            "selectedQuantity": "Half & Full",
            "productId": 14,
            "name": "Fish Curry",
            "cuisine": "Indian",
            "description": "Fish Gravy Masala",
            "isAdd": true,
            "category": "Starter",
            "quantityOption": [{\"option\":\"Half\", \"price\":100,  \"quantity\":2},{\"option\":\"Full\", \"price\":200,  \"quantity\":4}]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Custom mysql5dialect for group_concat**

```
package com.config.dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
public class CustomMySqlDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
    public CustomMySqlDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("group_concat"
                , new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat",new StringType()));
    }
}
```

Comment: CONCAT function returns a string, so how is your code working at all? Since mapping should go into a list. As far as response json is considered the result you get is correct based on your query (quantityOption in query is string and strings are surrounded with quotes in json).

Comment: Hi Mladen, yeah I am too confused how query result mapped to the list...it did not throw any error. As far as I know sql query does not support array type and in group_concat i have defined in custom mysql5 dialect support only string type.. so question how can I make it array ?? where I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your mapping is correct then with "fetch=FetchType.EAGER" then your query should be SELECT * FROM Product; and JPA will know based on your mappings how to populate both Product object and its child objects. After that json will also look like an array i believe.

Comment: yes Milden ..Thank you so much . I dont need to write HQL explicitly..Now I am able to fetch records and make  the required json. Kudos.